# log4j2.xml and log4j2-test.xml in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, classpath, log4j2

I have these two log files on my eclipse classpath, in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` respectively.

The problem is that `log4j2-test.xml` is higher priority and is always the chosen configuration file when running my application. How do I tell eclipse to ignore `log4j2-test.xml` and use `log4j2.xml` when running my application and to fall back to `log4j2-test.xml` when running unit tests?

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: yes i'm using maven. I solved the problem by adding this to the tomcat launch configuration: -Dlog4j.configurationFile="file:C:\blah...\src\main\resources\log4j2.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case that somebody had still some major trouble like me.
A working solution is:

- create a plugin MyLog4J that contains and provides the log4j jar files.
- add "Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered" the Manifest.MF of the MyLog4J plugin
- in your plugin that defines your actual application (e.g. Entrypoint) put log4j2.xml in the src folder
  AND add "Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: MyLog4J" to it's Manifest.MF

That **Eclipse-RegisterBuddy** is the key step to allow log4j to find the log4j2.xml file during startup!

Now you can re-use the MyLOG4J plugin in all your projects and have an individual log4j2.xml file for each application.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute this below statement in junit setup() method.This file should be avilable in the same package where your running this or you can provide the full path for this file.

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j2-test.xml");
```

Comment: That is a log4j-1.2 API, it does not work with log4j2.

Answer (score -1):

In log4j2 you can write the following

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager ctx = (org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager) LogManager.getContext(true);
ctx.setConfigLocation(LoggerTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log4j2-test.xml").toURI());
```

assuming log4j2-test.xml is in your classpath.